# What is the difference between these two commands?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $('.nav').bind('click',alert(0));  and:
    $('.nav').bind('click',function(){alert(0)})
```

Why does only the second command work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing here in the second command is wrapping a command in an anonymous function.  The handler for the click "event" requires a function so that it can be executed once the "event" is triggered.

You could do something like this also -

```
$('.nav').bind('click',showAlert);
function showAlert(){
  alert(0);
}
```

Here we pass the name of the function.

That is essentially the same as -

```
$('.nav').bind('click',function(){
  alert(0);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`jQuery.bind` requires a `function` as its second parameter. `alert` returns `void`, so there is no function to call.